# Splat block parameters for reduce/inject iterator

Tags: ruby, iterator, block

I have defined an array like this:

```
ary = [[0,1], [2,3]]
```

Running the following code:

```
ary.reduce(nil) do |a, i, k|
  puts "#{a.inspect} #{i.inspect} #{k.inspect}"
end
```

At each iteration I'd expect the variables `a`, `i`, and `k` to hold, respectively, the value of the accumulator (`nil`), the first element, and the second element of the inner array, i.e. I'd expect this output:

```
nil 0 1
nil 2 3
```

But instead the result is:

```
nil [0, 1] nil
nil [2, 3] nil
```

Why? How can I achieve the result I want?

Moreover, why the following code using `map` is working as I expect?

```
ary.map do |i, k|
  puts "#{i.inspect} #{k.inspect}"
end

# Output
# 0 1
# 2 3
```

What is the difference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Splat can work for one level. With `map`, the block parameter is `[0, 1]` and so on, which can be spalatted into `0` and `1`. With `inject`, the block parameters are `nil` and `[0, 1]`, which may be assigned to two variables (without splat), but not three. Splat does not work here because they are already splatted (they are two variables). In order to splat `[0, 1]`, you need to do that within the array, which requires a pair of parentheses.

```
{|a, (i, j)| ...}
```

Answer (score 3):

You want to do this:

```
A.reduce(nil) { |a, (i, j)| p i }
```

The difference between the default behavior of `map` and `reduce` is due to the special way Ruby handles blocks that receive single argument.  In such a case (i.e. `map`), it splats out an array for you, but for a block that is receiving multiple arguments (like `reduce`), it needs help to figure out what you want it to do.

Answer (score 2):

Lets try the below,to better understand:

```
A = [[0,1], [2,3], [4,5], [6,7]]
A.map { |i| print i } #=> [0, 1][2, 3][4, 5][6, 7]

A = [[0,1], [2,3], [4,5], [6,7]]
A.map { |i,j| print i,j ;print " " } #=> 01 23 45 67
```

This is because in the second code, the internal assignment happening in the below way for each element pass to the block:

```
i,j = [0,1]
i,j = [2,3] so on.
```

And in the first code, it is working like as below:

```
i = [0,1]
i = [2,3] so on.
```

So `Array#map` works good. Now in your case you didn't print `j`,only `i` so you get the single value.

```
A = [[0,1], [2,3], [4,5], [6,7]]
A.map { |i,j| print i ;print " " } #=> 0 2 4 6
```

Now to better understand about `Enum#inject`,see it [`A Simple Pattern for Ruby's inject method`](http://blog.flvorful.com/articles/2010/01/24/a-simple-pattern-for-rubys-inject-method). and [`Ruby's inject() and collect()`](http://polishinggems.blogspot.com/2011/05/rubys-inject-and-collect.html)